# My textbox value is appearing in my url and its still refreshing

Tags: html

heres my form

```
<form class="TextBox2Container" onsubmit="return noref(event)" method="POST ">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Answer" class="TextBoxtobeCorrected2" name="TextBoxtobeCorrected2"  onsubmit="showForm();return false">
                <button type='submit' class='RunButton2' onsubmit="return noref(event)" method="POST" ></button>
            </form>
```

then heres my javascript

```
    function noref(event) {
       var input = document.getElementsByClassName(".TextBoxtobeCorrected2").value
  if (input === "<p>Will It Run?</p>") {
    // Do something if the input matches the specific text
    $(".CORRECTANSS2").fadeIn("1000");
    $(".shade2").fadeIn("1000");
    $(".ResultContainerTrue2").fadeIn("1000");
  } else {
    // Close the HTML file if the input doesn't match the specific text
    $(function(){
      $(".RunButton2").fadeOut("1000");
      $(".RunButton2-1").fadeIn("1000");
      $(".TextBoxtobeCorrected2").fadeOut("1000");
      $(".TextBoxtobeCorrected2-1").fadeIn("1000");
      $(".Bat3rdBar").css("background-color","#E2E2E2");
      $(".Bat2ndBar").css("background-color","#FFDE59");
      $(".Bat1stBar").css("background-color","#FFDE59");
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  console.log('wala not workin ');
  return false;
}
```

its refreshing and the textbox value still appearing  in my url i hvae no idea how to fix it i tried everything on my end and here on stackoverflow

Comment: Try `event.preventdefault()` while submitting the form.